# How to get a file's last modified date in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm porting a small MVC 5 website to MVC 6 to spot breaking changes.  Stuff is breaking.

The MVC 5 code uses `@File.GetLastWriteTime(this.Server.MapPath(this.VirtualPath))` to get the timestamp, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529417/asp-net-mvc-getting-last-modified-date-fileinfo-of-view).  Apparently in MVC 6, the .cshtml page no longer has `Server` or `VirtualPath` members.  What's the new incantation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revisiting my own question 18 months later...  the framework is now ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC and it seems the framework, documentation and best practices have changed a bit.

You should use a FileProvider as described in the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers).  There's no point in recreating that article here, but be sure to:

- Add an IHostingEnvironment to the Startup **constructor** parameters, and save it off in a local variable, as described in the docs
- In Startup.ConfigureServices(), call `services.AddSingleton(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider);` to register an IFileProvider service, also described in the docs
- Add an IFileProvider to the controller's **constructor** parameters, and save it off in a local variable

Then to actually get the last modified date, the controller will look something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    public HomeController(IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        DateTimeOffset lastModifiedDate = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(@"Views\Home\Index.cshtml").LastModified;
        // use it wisely...
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative solution for @PaulWilliam's asnwer**

In cases when you can't use a File provider for any reasons, getting a file's last modified date can be done using the `System.IO.File` static class and it's method `GetLastWriteTime` or `GetLastWriteTimeUtc` which returns a `DateTime` obj:

```
DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath);
```

Note that the non-utc method, `GetLastWriteTime` returns the last-modified date based on the server/filesystem time.

Other than that, and all the write-read methods, `System.IO.File` also contains methods that help retrieve data as last access time, creation time etc. Not only getter methods, but setters aswell.

Docs: [File Class - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-2.2)

---

Also worth pointing out that you can use the `GetAttributes`/`SetAttributes` methods to work with `FileAttributes` enums which are used for defining a file's status as `Hidden`, `Compressed` etc.

Docs: [File.GetAttributes(String) Method - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=netcore-2.2#System_IO_File_GetAttributes_System_String_) and [FileAttributes Enum - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=netcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `ApplicationBasePath` from the `IApplicationEnvironment` service.

```
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _env;

public FileController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    _env= appEnv;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var myModel = _env.ApplicationBasePath;
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Then you can make your own path calculation, like this, for example:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var myFileVirtualPath = "/ab/c.d"
        var myModel = Path.Combine(_env.ApplicationBasePath, myFileVirtualPath);
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

@(new System.IO.FileInfo(new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(Environment.CurrentDirectory).GetFileInfo(this.Path).PhysicalPath).CreationTime)